# Stop VBA Macro from adding extra double quotes to excel row data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA Macro which saves excel rows to .svg. The code seems to be working perfectly except that it's adding an extra double quote in the svg documents where the double quotes appear. This is the VBA macro that I'm using:

```
Sub SaveRowsAsSVGs()

Dim wb As Excel.Workbook, wbNew As Excel.Workbook
Dim wsSource As Excel.Worksheet, wsTemp As Excel.Worksheet
Dim r As Long, c As Long
Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Images")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'will overwrite existing files without asking
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

r = 1
Do Until Len(Trim(wsSource.Cells(r, 1).Value)) = 0
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set wsTemp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

For c = 2 To 7
    wsTemp.Cells((c - 1) * 2 - 1, 1).Value = wsSource.Cells(r, c).Value
Next c

wsTemp.Move
Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsTemp = wbNew.Worksheets(1)
Dim myPath As String
myPath = "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\MJOMBA\Images\"
wbNew.SaveAs myPath & wsSource.Cells(r, 1).Value & ".svg", xlCSV
'wbNew.SaveAs "cell.Text" & r & ".svg", xlCSV 'new way
wbNew.Close
ThisWorkbook.Activate
r = r + 1
Loop

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End Sub
```

Below is an example .svg code (for demonstration purpose)

This piece of .svg code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
```

Becomes

```
<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""iso-8859-1""?>
```

This is not the intended behaviour. How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: Looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for me. Why would you use a "Save as csv" function to create a svg file?

Comment: Could you not directly [Print](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/printstatement) or [Write](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/writeline-method) the correct values in the required file?

Comment: Anyway, you are explicitly asking for doubled double quote by saying to save as xlCSV. Maybe it wold work better with Text format (xlTextWindows or xlUnicodeText)

Comment: Nothing happens even after I replace xlCSV with either of the two suggested formats - xlTextWindows or xlUnicodeText.

Comment: try xlTextPrinter

Comment: xlTextPrinter works but the problem is that it's creating word breaks where it's not necesarry causing the svg file to throw an error. Is there a way we can just save the text as it is without interfering at all?

Comment: See my second comment.